# Symplectic form of a coadjoint orbit of a compact connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}.$ Denote by $\mathfrak{g}^*$ the dual space of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $r$ be an element of $\mathfrak{g}^*$ such that $G_r$ the stabilizer of $r$ under the coadjoint action is a maximal torus of $G$. Denote by $\mathcal{O}_r$ the coadjoint orbit of $G$ which pass through $r$.

$\mathcal{O}_r$ is endowed with a 2-form which is a symplectic form
$$\omega_\alpha(\hat{X},\hat{Y})= -\alpha([X,Y]), \alpha \in \mathfrak{g}^*, \quad X,Y, \in \mathfrak{g}. $$
Often it is more convenient to choose
an inner product $\langle . , . \rangle$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ to identify $\mathfrak{g}^*$ with $\mathfrak{g}$. Once such an inner product has been chosen, we can write the 2-form as
$$\omega_\lambda(\hat{X},\hat{Y}) = −\langle \lambda, [X,Y] \rangle, \lambda, X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}.$$

If $G$ is semisimple, then we choose the killing form denoted $k$ to define $\omega$:
$$\omega_\lambda(\hat{X},\hat{Y}) = −k(\lambda, [X,Y]).$$

> $\textbf{Question}$: In the case where $G$ is a compact connected Lie group (not necessarily semisimple), why does the 2-form
> $$\omega_\lambda(\hat{X},\hat{Y}) = −k(\lambda, [X,Y]), \lambda, X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}.$$
> defined using the killing form defines a symplectic form on the coadjoint orbit $ \mathcal{O_r}$ of $G$ ?

This a follow-up question of my questions here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430926/question-about-the-k%c3%a4hler-structure-on-generic-coadjoint-orbits/431200#431200 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431284/compact-coadjoint-orbits?noredirect=1#comment1110075_431284. LSpice explained that If $G$ is a compact connected Lie group we may assume that it is semisimple, since there are a compact, semisimple Lie subgroup $G'$ of $G$, the derived group of $G$, and a torus $T$ in $G$, the maximal central torus in $G$, such that the multiplication map $G' \times T \to G$ is a covering map.  Could anyone give more details about this please?

Answer (score 1):

In case of non-null cohomology, you have to add to classical KKS 2 form a Souriau cocycle, as explained in the book of Jean-Louis Koszul "Introduction to Symplectic Geometry" in chapter 4 and 5:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-13-3987-5